# CSVExcelStorage not skipping header with pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I'm trying to skip the header of a CSV file when loading it to Pig.

```
REGISTER /usr/hdp/2.3.4.0-3485/pig/lib/piggybank.jar;
define CSVExcelStorage org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage; 

transactions = load 'hdfs://vm1.local:8020/user/root/transcations/trans.csv' USING CSVExcelStorage(',','NO_MULTILINE', 'UNIX', 'SKIP_INPUT_HEADER')
```

but when I dump `transactions` I get the header too.
I use Apache Pig 0.15
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to above problem is 
--> DEFINE CSVExcelStorage org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage(',', 'NO_MULTILINE', 'UNIX', 'SKIP_INPUT_HEADER');. 
--> transactions = load 'hdfs://vm1.local:8020/user/root/transcations/trans.csv' USING CSVExcelStorage();

What I found that conventional way of defining the alias to UDF is not working in this case.